# Как извлечь общий метод

Tags: c#, рефакторинг

Здравствуйте. Есть два метода, отличающиеся лишь одной строчкой. Очень бы хотелось объединить их в один, но никак не могу придумать как это сделать.

```
  public long FindPosition(Predicate<T> match)
    {
      if(match == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("match");

      long position = FirstItemPosition;

      while(position != End)
      {
        Item<T> item = GetItemAtPosition(position);

        if(match(item.Value))
          return position;

        position = item.Next;
      }

      return position;
    }

    private long FindPosition(Predicate<Item<T>> match)
    {
      if(match == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("match");

      long position = FirstItemPosition;

      while(position != End)
      {
        Item<T> item = GetItemAtPosition(position);

        if(match(item))
          return position;

        position = item.Next;
      }

      return position;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Здесь не нужно выполнять `Extract Method`, и не нужно делать шаблонный класс. Нужно просто **выкинуть** первую из перегрузок `FindPosition`:

> У второй перегрузки (которая принимает `Predicate<Item<T>>`) совершенно очевидная семантика — она возвращает первый `Item<T>`, удовлетворяющий предикату. Если таких нет, она возвращает `End`.

- Необходимость первой перегрузки лично мне представляется крайне сомнительной. Вместо того, чтобы писать дополнительный метод, проще написать эквивалентый предикат `Predicate<Item<T>>`, который будет выполнять какие-то действия с `item.Value` — сделать это можно всегда:

  ```
  Predicate<Item<T>> predicate = item => item.Value > 0;
  ```
- В качестве разумной альтернативы можете рассмотреть применение [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx) к вашей последовательности, дабы лишний раз *не изобретать велосипед.*

> Нестрого говоря, сделать это можно путем превращения вашего метода `Item<T> GetItemAtPosition(position)` в `IEnumerable<Item<T>>`.

---

- Если так получилось, что `FindPosition(Predicate<T> match)` никак нельзя выкинуть, а `LINQ` вы использовать не планируете, то совершите обратное преобразование:

  ```
  public long FindPosition(Predicate<T> match)
  {
      return FindPosition(item => match(item.Value));
  }

  private long FindPosition(Predicate<Item<T>> match)
  {
      ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Необходимость первой перегрузки в том, что структура Item может использоваться только внутри сборки. Внешний код об этой структуре ничего не знает, ему возвращается только поле Value.

Comment: @Veikedo Такого рода ограничения обычно неплохо отражать в тексте вопроса. Обновил ответ.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, да, это было просто :) Большое спасибо за помощь. Ps. FirstOrDefault здесь, кстати, использовать не получится потому, что возвращается позиция в потоке Stream, где этот Item записан, а не сам Item

Comment: @Veikedo Ну вот, видите, вы утаили от нас еще одну важную деталь из постановки задачи `:)`

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, мне показалось, что эту деталь из сигнатуры метода видно :). В любом случае, еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вам поможет использование шаблонного класса:

```
public class MyClass<T> 
{
     public long FindPosition(Predicate<T> match)
     {
         return 0;
     }

}
```

**Использование:**

```
MyClass<int> obj = new MyClass<int>();
MyClass<List<int>> obj2 = new MyClass<List<int>>();
```